# How to get access to the 'Setup -> Create -> BigObjects' page?

Tags: permissions, setup, big-object

How to get access to the 'Setup -> Create -> BigObjects' page?

It was working fine recently and now I'm receiving **Insufficient Privileges**

[image: Insufficient Privileges]

Comment: Are you syste, - admin?

Answer (score -1):

This is reported bug to Salesforce with bug number W-5836430. Waiting for fix.